# Keep place in html layouts

Tags: html, css

today my question is asking how I could make an html page layout stay the same even for any different proportional screen size. For example, I'm creating an html page on a 15.6" 16:9 ratio screen size and I want to make it stay the same for when changing screen sizes.

Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;          
}
#section {
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;        
}
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
   padding:5px;      
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
<h1>City Gallery</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">
London<br>
Paris<br>
Tokyo<br>
</div>

<div id="section">
<h2>London</h2>
<p>
London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
</p>
<p>
Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So now I want the footer to stay at the bottom so yeah, how would I do that?

Comment: Post some pictures of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your footer CSS with this one

```
#footer {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    bottom: 2px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And the full Code should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;          
}
#section {
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;        
}
#footer {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    bottom: 2px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
<h1>City Gallery</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">
London<br>
Paris<br>
Tokyo<br>
</div>

<div id="section">
<h2>London</h2>
<p>
London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
</p>
<p>
Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure about what you want to get, neverthless you can set specific rules based on aspect-ratio of the output device es:

```
...

@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
.foo {
...
     }
}
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 4/3) {
.foo {
...
     }
}
```

and so on...

there are alo other ways to achive that kind of transformations, in my opinion media queries is the easiest.